# JavaScript: If var statements are executed first, then why does this not work?

Tags: javascript

I tried the following in JavaScript (Firefox 3.5, Windows XP):

```
(function(){
    window.foobar = 'Welcome!';
})();

var foobar = 'PWN3D!';

alert(foobar);
```

The output was 'PWN3D!'. Why did my code PWN me? I thought `var name = value;` executed first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/ecma-262.htm) (page 87):

> A variable with an Initialiser is assigned the value of its AssignmentExpression when the VariableStatement is executed, not when the variable is created.

So the `var` causes the variable to be created first, but the value (`'PWN3D!'`) is assigned to it in the normal execution order.

Comment: To prove a point, you can insert a `if ('foobar' in window) {console.log("Var foobar is declared but not initialized, its value is " + foobar)}`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by `var` statements being executed first. The code you have written looks to be working exactly as I would have expected:

- An anonymous function is created
- The anonymous function is executed, which sets `foobar` to "Welcome!"
- The `foobar` variable is set to "PWN3D!"
- An alert box is raised with the current value of `foobar`, "PWN3D!"

Answer (score 1):

Your alert statement sees the local variable, foobar and alerts its value as it is higher on the scope chain than window.foobar.

Comment: (In this case, window.foobar and the local variable foobar happen to be the same thing since you are at the top level of execution.)

Also, it will execute the anonymous function first, and then move on to the local variable assignment "PWN3D!", finishing with the alert which will output as you've seen, "PWN3D!".